# How Deserialize json result to display them on HTML / CSS Styled format?

Tags: php, api, json

I just got started with Google API for Custom Search Engine, and I have succeded on doing my first request like this:

**My_first_Search.php**

```
 require_once 'apis/apiClient.php';
 require_once 'apis/contrib/apiCustomsearchService.php';
 session_start();

 $client = new apiClient();
 $client->setApplicationName('Google CustomSearch PHP Starter Application');
 // Docs: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html
 // My developer key (simple api key).
 $client->setDeveloperKey('***********************************');
 $search = new apiCustomsearchService($client);


  // executing a search with your custom search id.
  $result = $search->cse->listCse('burrito', array(
  'cx' => '123456789123546789:*******', // The custom search engine ID to scope this search query.
  ));
 print "<pre>" . print_r($result, true) . "</pre>";

 // executing a search with the URL of a linked custom search engine.
 $result = $search->cse->listCse('burrito', array(
 'cref' => 'http://www.google.com/cse/samples/vegetarian.xml',
  ));
 print "<pre>" . print_r($result, true) . "</pre>";
```

**The output:** [This file](http://homepage-changer.com/search/google.php) output the results correctly for the keyword `burrito` in a JSON format

How can I desalinize then manipulate the result using a for-each loop to get:

```
  - Result title
  - Result description
  - URL
```

[Click here to see the JSON output to be manipulated](http://homepage-changer.com/search/google.php)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "this file" is not outputting json. JSON is the textual representation of a variable assignment in JS,. e.g. the right-hand side of `var x = ...json here...`. That dump is a PHP data structure, which has been produced by decoding a json string.

in other words, don't get hung up on the fact that you're getting JSON - once it's decoded, it's just another PHP array, and you use normal PHP array operations and indexes to get at your data.

e.g.

```
$arr['queries']['nextPage'][0]['title'] // Google Custom Search - burrito
```